# How to glob in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, glob

Is there a simple way (ie. library) in **React** that allows you to get all file paths with a certain pattern from a folder in the src (or public) directory?
Something 'Reacty' like this?

```
    import Globber from "glob-react"

    function globbing () {
      return (Globber.glob(pattern='./folder/**/*.txt'))
    }
```

If not, what would be the simplest thing?

Comment: What platform are you expecting this to run on?

Comment: It's a create-react-app app.

Comment: So are you expecting this to run client side in the browser?

Comment: That is the case, Yes.

Comment: You can't just get access to the local filesystem like that in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about libraries, there is just JS glob:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob

Or "Fast Glob":
https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-glob

Which should be fine to install through your package manager into your project, and import into any of your libraries.